# Correctly archiving cross referencing Objective-C dictionaries

Tags: objective-c, nskeyedarchiver, nscoding

I have a system which I am trying to archive. The main data which I need to store is in two different trees. I will simplify it for examle

Class A
{
  B* Data 
}

Class B
{
  NSString* ParentKeyToATree
}

I am trying to archive this data where there is a dictionary of A objects and a dictionary of B objects. Obviously they are cross dependent, and I would not want Class A to be unarchived and have two separate instances of all cross-referenced B objects? If I were to unarchive the B Dictionary first, I could store the key in place of the pointer and then re-populate the pointer on unarchive, but this would force me to pass a reference to the A tree in through a global or singleton which I would like to avoid. Is there a good answer to this problem that is clean? I realize I could store a key in the A tree and avoid this, but it is this way as it is very speed sensitive code.

Comment: When unarchiving leave the keys in place and once unarchiving is complete run through the class B instances and resolve the pointers to the class A objects.  The keys then become obsolete so perhaps make them type `id` so they can either hold an `NSString` key (before resolution) or `A *` (after resolution). An additional issue with that is the key should be `strong` but the `A *` should be `weak`.